# Exponentiation as Limit of a diagram

Tags: category-theory

universal constructions in category theory are connected to limits or co-limits of diagrams. For example, a pullback of a diagram A->B<-C is a cone limit for that - e.g. A<-D->C.

Now, exponentiation is also a universal construction; namely it is a morphism of the form  B^A X A -> B. So, how would the diagram involved here looks like? in other words, the exponentiation is a cone over what diagram?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Exponentiation $(-)^A$ is the right adjoint to the product $(-)\times A$, so you can think of $B^A$, together with the evaluation morphism $\mathrm{ev}:B^A\times A\to B$, as the terminal object in the slice category $(-\times A\downarrow B)$ of objects $X$ equipped with an arrow $X\times A\to B$.

Hence the precise answer is that the exponential, equipped with its evaluation, is the limit of the empty diagram into the category $(-\times A\downarrow B)$.

Keywords: adjoint functors, slice category.

Comment: thank you very much @Jackozee Hakkiuz